# Summation of Exponential

Tags: exponential-sum

The equation below is a posteriori density under the assumption that the prior distribution for $\mu$ is normal.
[image]

And I wonder why do the highlighted portions where $\mu$ and $x_{k}$ are swapped when expressing the multiplication of exponential quotients into summation.
Can anyone please explain or is it the mistake?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you know that $x^2 = (-x)^2$?  Do you know that $a-b$ is the negative of $b-a$?

Answer (score 0):

the aim to swap $(x_k-\mu)^2=(\mu-x_k)^2$ is to show that the posterior density (now the rv is $\mu$, because $x_i$ are known data) is still gaussian.

Next step is to observe that

$$\Sigma_k(\mu-x_k)^2=n(\mu-\overline{x})^2+C$$

where $C$ is an expression without $\mu$ so it can be canceled and included in the normalizing constant $\alpha$... and so on